# Transformation matrix determined by a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

So I'm working trough a set of problems in preparation for a Linear Algerba exam, I'm stuck on this one:

Let $\{x,y,z\}$ be the basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$  and $A:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ is a linear operator given by the matrix: $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & -2 & -5 \\
        0 & 2 & 2 \\
        2 & 2 & 4 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

a) Determine the transformation matrix $A$ with respect to the basis $\{x+y, y+z, z+x\}.$

b)Determine if $A$ is a linear transformation.

What is the process in determining the transformation matrix with respect to a new basis when you already have a transformation matrix with respect to another?

I believe that for the basis $\{x, y, z\}$ by multiplying with the $A$ matrix we get the mapping to some vector given by:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
-x -2y -5z \\ 2y+2z \\ 2x+2y+4z \end{bmatrix}
$$

So does the new transformation have to map $\ x+y,\ y+z, \ z+x$ to the same thing as above or am I mistaken?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Basis_and_coordinates may be worth a read (this is my go-to guide for how to understand basises(?) and changing between them)

Answer (score 1):

For question 2, $A$ is a linear transformation because it can be represented by a matrix.

For question 1, first of all, we have
$$A\vec{x}=-\vec{x}+2\vec{z}\\
A\vec{y}=-2\vec{x}+2\vec{y}+2\vec{z}\\
A\vec{z}=-5\vec{x}+2\vec{y}+4\vec{z}$$

You can see that the columns of $A$ are the coefficients of the vector obtained when you apply $A$ to the basis.

Same idea leads to the matrix under another basis. We have 
$$A(\vec{x}+\vec{y})=-3\vec{x}+2\vec{y}+4\vec{z}$$
using the above equations.

Now write $-3\vec{x}+2\vec{y}+4\vec{z}$ in terms of $\vec{x}+\vec{y}, \vec{y}+\vec{z},\vec{z}+\vec{x}$, by some computation
$$-3\vec{x}+2\vec{y}+4\vec{z}=-\frac{5}{2}(\vec{x}+\vec{y})+\frac{9}{2} (\vec{y}+\vec{z})-\frac{1}{2}(\vec{z}+\vec{x})$$

So the first column of the new matrix should be
$$\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{5}{2}\\\frac{9}{2}\\-\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$

You can find the other columns using similar way.